# android - Periodically polling a server and displaying response as a notification

Tags: android, notifications

I'm building an android app where I need to fetch some notification data (text) from a server every three hours and display it as a notification using NotificationManager. I've looked  [here](http://simpleandroidtutorials.blogspot.in/2012/06/periodically-update-data-from-server-in.html)  and  [here](http://androidideasblog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/alarmmanager-and-notificationmanager.html)  but they seem pretty confusing to me.

How can I get this done?

Comment: What have you tried? What part of this (rather broad) feature are you getting stuck on?

Comment: One of the example uses BroadcastReceiver, Service and AlarmManager and no proper explanation is given as to how the code works and I'm not able to figure how these three features are required/used

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use AlarmManager with a pending intent to start a service, make the API call to the server from within your service, create the notification, then stop the service.

```
/**
 * Set up recurring location updates using AlarmManager
 */
public void setUpAlarm(Application context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
    PendingIntent pending_intent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarm_mgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm_mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), YOUR_INTERVAL, pending_intent);
}
```

The above code will set a pending intent to start your service for whatever interval you set with the YOUR_INTERVAL variable.  From here, just create your "MyService" class to make your API call and build your notification once you get a response from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to create a background service for this, here is a good tutorial:

http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html