# How not to disable internet connection while screen is locked?

Tags: android, service, powermanager

How not to disable internet connection in service while screen is locked or application went to background?
I have such problem. I need service in my application to send request to the server every 5 minutes. But after locking screen internet connection stops. I heard about Power Manager but i dont know hot to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your service is solely for running every 5 minutes you should use the AlarmManager instead.

[Have a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20887270/android-periodically-polling-a-server-and-displaying-response-as-a-notificatio)

Anyway, the service should not lose internet connection when running in the background unless you bound it to your activities lifetime.